# Choosing a blower for a Pneumatic Conveyor

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, pumps, airflow, pneumatic

Basically we are designing a pneumatic conveyor system for transferring 11 tons of beans per hour.
We need to decide on the specifications of the blower. What are the calculations necessary to decide on a blower wrt. static pressure, flow velocity and type of blower?

Comment: So what type of conveyor ? First work out how much air you need then work out how to deliver it...

Comment: Beans are hard to convey pneumatically except for straight up. You need to show the plant layout and tube runs that you are planning. Going sideways any distance would require some experiments and probably involve slug flow. You want to be able to start up the blower and have it blow out a clogged tube after a shutdown that leaves a lot of beans in the tube.  Also, do you care about the appearance of the beans? There's going to be quite a lot of damage to them, which might be okay if they are going to be cooked and processed. This is fairly specialized, and I would hire a consultant.